# Nodejs child_process list

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'd like to know how many child processes are running under the current process. I tried running `child_process.exec('pgrep -- P $1|xargs')` but that returns 8 processes before I've spawned any.

Comment: Presumably you can simply keep track yourself in node? Just keep a tally everytime you create one, and decrease the tally on the child's `exit` event?

Comment: yes this was the solution i ended up at. thanks :)